# why are chrome's bookmark icon codes too long when exporting to html?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, microsoft-edge

For example, this is the entry of Superuser when I opened bookmark html in notepad.

```
<DT><A HREF="https://superuser.com/" ADD_DATE="1674863395" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Super User</A>
```

As you can see, it's a long-winded string for Icon parameter.

What is this and why does it have to be so long? Can I not shorten this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use a web link shorten tool.  Lots around.   .......  https://www.shorturl.at/

Answer (score 1):

> What is this

It is a [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs).

> and why does it have to be so long

It is a whole file as base64 in a url.

> **Should you shorten it**

**No, it doesn't make much of a difference and in the html file itself is written**

```html
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
```

> How can you shorten this

You can shorten it by grabbing the [Favicon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel#attr-icon) from the head of the website and replacing the Data URL with it.

In your example it would be `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/Img/favicon.ico`

So your bookmark would be `<DT><A HREF="https://superuser.com/" ADD_DATE="1674863395" ICON="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/superuser/Img/favicon.ico">Super User</A>`